# What is best practice for restricting user permissions when editing model instances

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-permissions

I am building a simple app using [User Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id1).

My app has 3 models:

- **Users** : The standard Django user model
- **Locations**: A model for an office (address, site name, etc)
- **Employees**: A model for an employee (name, email, etc)

I also have a series of views that allow a user to login, create, and edit locations/sites, etc.

What I want to know, is what is the best practice to restrict editing of model instances to those which the user has created? E.g. with no amendment, two users could create data and both could edit the others. How do I restrict this to editing their own?

I know the long form way is to put a `ForeignKey(User)` on each model to restrict the view with a `queryset`, but this seems lengthy and cumbersome. Is there a Django trick I am missing? Perhaps a decorator?

What's the best practice?

Comment: If users are to only edit their own object, IanAuld's answer is the way to go.  Otherwise you could have a set of users who could edit all objects, you could control this by putting these users in a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to edit your models so that they have an `owner` or `user` field that is a `ForeignKey` to the creator.

```
class Locations(models.Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

And in your views:

```
def edit_location(request, location_id):
    location = Locations.objects.get(pk=location_id)
    if request.user is not location.owner:
        # return a 401 or redirect to somewhere
    else:
        # do stuff
```

You can use Django's [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) option if each `Location` and `User` can have multiple relationships. For example:

```
class Locations(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User)

user = User.objects.create(username='Ian')
location = Locations.objects.create(...)
location.owners.add(user)
```

And then the `User`/`Locations` are available on both:

```
>>> location.owners.all()
[<User: Ian>]
>>> user.locations_set.all()
[<Locations: ...>]
```

The set on `User` will be automatically created and it will be named `<Model Name>_set`.

You can then use the `in` operator to check ownership:

```
def edit_location(request, location_id):
        location = Locations.objects.get(pk=location_id)
        if request.user in location.owners.all():
            # return a 401 or redirect to somewhere
        else:
            # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I wanted to extend this, so that 2 users could edit the same data. Then a foreign key won't work (as this is 1-1). Any ideas?

Comment: `ManyToManyField` should work assuming each `User` can have many `Locations` and each `Location` can have many `User`'s